# Why Does the Kafka Producer Close for Each Commit in Flink's `EXACTLY_ONCE` Mode

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I use the `flink-connector-kafka` in my Flink application. The semantic is set to `EXACTLY_ONCE`. I see the following log that indicates that the Kafka producer has been closed and reconnected:

```
Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 0 ms.
Proceeding to force close the producer since pending requests could not be completed within timeout 0 ms.
```

Looking at the source code, I found the close call from the producer commit function. The commit function calls the `recycleTransactionalProducer` in finally block, and the `recycleTransactionalProducer` funcation call the close function, which prints the log. Why is/does the Kafka producer has been close for each commit?

Source code from package:
`org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka;`
`org.apache.kafka.clients.producer;`

```java
@Override
protected void commit(FlinkKafkaProducer.KafkaTransactionState transaction) {
    if (transaction.isTransactional()) {
        try {
            transaction.producer.commitTransaction();
        } finally {
            recycleTransactionalProducer(transaction.producer);
        }
    }
}

private void recycleTransactionalProducer(FlinkKafkaInternalProducer<byte[], byte[]> producer) {
    availableTransactionalIds.add(producer.getTransactionalId());
    producer.flush();
    producer.close(Duration.ofSeconds(0));
}

private void close(Duration timeout, boolean swallowException) {
    long timeoutMs = timeout.toMillis();
    if (timeoutMs < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The timeout cannot be negative.");
    log.info("Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = {} ms.", timeoutMs);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Problems-with-FlinkKafkaProducer-closing-after-timeoutMillis-9223372036854775807-ms-td39488.html :

> ... when using exactly-once semantics for the FlinkKafkaProducer, there is a fixed-sized pool of short-living Kafka producers that are created for each concurrent checkpoint.
> When a checkpoint begins, the FlinkKafkaProducer creates a new producer for that checkpoint. Once said checkpoint completes, the producer for that checkpoint is attempted to be closed and recycled.
> So, it is normal to see logs of Kafka producers being closed if you're using an exactly-once transactional FlinkKafkaProducer.